# get increment ID in info.phtml page on customer detail order

Tags: php, magento

I need to show the current order increment ID in the order details screen, on the client page, via the info.phtml file.

If I use `$this->getOrder();` or `$this->getOrderId();` or `$this->getIncrementId();` does not return anything.

If I use `$order->getOrder();` Or `$order->getOrderId();` Or `$order->getIncrementId();` Returns an error as:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getIncrementId () on a
>   non-object

What am I missing?

Comment: Whatever `$order` is in your case, it is not an object and therefore cannot have a member function `getOrder()` etc., and that is why you get the error.

Comment: But `$this->getOrder();` should work, should not it?

Comment: how are you using the info.phtml, what is block class?

Comment: It should work out of the box. I think you changed block class from the one installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope this helps.

```
$this->getOrder()->getRealOrderId()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below.

code located in app\design\frontend\base\default\template\sales\order\info.phtml

```
$_order = $this->getOrder();
echo $_order->getRealOrderId();
```

Answer (score -1):

Please elaborate a bit more. I mean can you post the function. Try it.

`$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$order->load(Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->getLastOrderId());
$lastOrderId = $order->getIncrementId();`

Comment: This function `$this->getOrder ();` does not cause an error, but returns no information.